# How to determine the single-qubit phase?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-phase-estimation, superconducting-quantum-computing

In some works it is suggested to find the qubit phase by the following method:

1. Apply $X/2$ (or $Y/2$) gate - preparing the qubit in superposition.
2. Detune the qubit by flux pulse, for example here from $6 GHz$ (red dot) to $5 GHz$ (blue dot):
   [image]
3. Wait for a variable delay.

4.1. Apply $X/2$ gate, readout and write the result.

4.2. Apply $Y/2$ gate, readout and write the result.

4.3. Apply $I$ gate, readout and write the result.

Such sequence is described [here](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emartinisgroup/theses/Chen2018.pdf) on page 155.

I have two questions for described sequence:

1. What is the qubit frequency during applying the detuning pulse? If it is equal to detuning (for example, $1 GHz$ for the Figure above), why?
2. How can I determine the qubit phase from collected data?